# Is this Incorrect Usage of Rails Routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

a couple days ago i started a project- i'm not using restful routes and my whole file looks like this `match '/a/b' => 'a#b'` over and over.  Are these kind of routes considered incorrect or bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is considered bad practice. Instead you should use `resource` or `resources` liberally and do your best to follow the seven RESTful actions. Your best bet is to read [The Ruby on Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) as it provides many great examples!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could fit your routing into some kind of RESTful action, but if not, at least clump  your controllers together in blocks. I doubt all of your controllers will just have a single route?  If so, consider Sinatra, unless you are just playing around, then this conversation is pointless. If you are not using this in a real production app, your real question should be "Where do i learn how to use routing effectively"?